# Strange detail dataset memo-fields encoding in TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, master-detail, tclientdataset, memo

Good day, all!

I'm using a TClientDataSet, connected to master-detail dataset. At first, save data (for futher data exchange)

*cdsImpExp.SaveToFile(aFileName, dfXML);*

In obtained file memo-fields are written in internal encoding (what encoding, BTW?):
T_PATIENTS_MEMO="!?@02:0 4;O MB>9 "  - for the master dataset

T_OBSERVATION_MEMO="!?@02:0 4;O MB>9 " - for the detail dataset

Now do

*cdsImpExp.LoadFromFile(aFileName);*

and try to process every field. I'm getting very strange behaviour for memo-fields content. At first I tried to read theese fields as:

*FieldValue := Field.AsString;*

In master dataset memo-field contains correct string in desired encoding (win-1251). In detail dataset memo-field contains the same char sequence as in input file (!?@02:0 4;O MB>9). Ok. I try this:

```
  if Field.DataType = ftMemo then
  begin
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    TMemoField(Field).SaveToStream(ms);
     ms.Position := 0;
     SetString(FieldValue, PChar(ms.Memory), ms.Size);
```

And FieldValue contains some like 'Справка㐠㬄伄 этой㼠䀄㸄' (some chars are right and some chars are in Japaneese encoding).

What I do wrong? How can I read memo-field values from xml-file for the detail dataset?
Thanks for your help.

I have Delphi XE Update 1.